# Multiple SSL certificate on one domain

Tags: ssl, encryption, nginx, https, ssl-certificate

We use nginx for SSL termination and rotate ssl certificate yearly. But whenever we rotate we send notification to user about date and time when we are going to apply the change and they have to make changes on their end at same time. There are few enterprise tools which few customers use, and they need same certificate loaded in their trust store.

So I wanted to check if there is any way to deploy two certificates on one domain temporarily like for a week. For that period both the certificate works, so customers can move to newer certificate over that period. May be some kind of certificate chaining or something which can help us solve this problem.

PS: I am sorry if sounds too stupid, just want to listen others view on this problem.

Thanks,
GG

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2):

While it would be possible to send any number of certificates to the peer (that's what you do when sending intermediate certs) it is expected that the certificate matching the hostname is the first and the following are the chain certificates in proper order. A client will not just look into all the certificates and pick the ones which look best.

But it should be possible that you give the client the new certificate in advance and it can add this one to the list of trusted certificates, without replacing the old one. And as long as you serve the old certificate the client will find this as trusted, once you move over to the new one the client will find this as trusted too.

Even better might be to use your own CA to issue all the certificates. Then the client needs only once to install this CA as trusted and then it will automatically trust any new certificates issued by this CA, no matter if you rotate yearly or daily. This is how it works in the browsers, where google or whatever does not need to ship the new certificates to all browsers but instead these are signed by a CA trusted by the browser.

Comment: What do you mean by own CA? We use digicert to issue all our certs, so if digicert is added as trusted CA then new one should work automatically?

Comment: Then why all your clients need to update their configuration whenever you rotate the certificate? If they trust digicert then they should trust your new certificate without any kind of updates on their site.

Comment: Cool make sense, that's what my assumption was. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The certificate is binded exactly to the FQDN which the Users type on the address bar. If you procure a Public SSL certificates from the likes of Symantec , Digicert, Thawte, etc your clients need not update their certificate store reason being the Public Certificate Authority (CA) roots & intermediate certificates are well known and are very much a part of all the Leading OS certificate stores.